Genson with jakarta in java21 and tomcat 10.1
I use genson 1.6 and I must migrate in tomcat 10.1.
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.owlike</groupId>
    <artifactId>genson</artifactId>
    <version>1.6</version>
</dependency>

I'm migrating all library, and now i have this error in genson's library
In class JerseyAutoDiscoverable , genson use the old package 'javax.ws.rs.core.' rather than 'jakarta.ws.rs.core.' not compatible with tomcat 10.x
And at runtime i have this error

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.ws.rs.core.FeatureContext     at
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1353)

I use the last version available, 1.6
What can i do?

it's not possibly. Genson is dead

Don't know much about genson but I think you could :

fork genson to make it support jakarta
use GSON alternative User guide here which is quite similar and doesn't rely on javax / jakarta library.

Maven coordinates of GSON :
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
    <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
    <version>2.11.0</version>
</dependency>

